# React-redux connect()'s mapStateToProps being called multiple times on react-router navigation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, redux

I have a simple router (started with `redux-router` and switched to `react-router` to eliminate variables).

```
<Router history={history}>
  <Route component={Admin} path='/admin'>
    <Route component={Pages} path='pages'/>
    <Route component={Posts} path='posts'/>
  </Route>
</Router>
```

Admin component is basically just `{this.props.children}` with some nav; it is not a `connect`ed component.

Pages component is a `connect`ed component with `mapStateToProps()` like so:

```
function mapStateToProps (state) {
  return {
    pages: state.entities.pages
  };
}
```

Posts is even more interesting:

```
function mapStateToProps (state) {
  let posts = map(state.entities.posts, post => {
    return {
      ...post,
      author: findWhere(state.entities.users, {_id: post.author})
    };
  }

  return {
    posts
  };
}
```

And then when I load the page or switch between Posts/Pages routes I get the following in my console.log().

```
// react-router navigate to /posts

Admin render()
posts: map state to props
Posts render()
posts: map state to props
Posts render()
posts: map state to props

// react-router navigate to /pages

Admin render()
pages: map state to props
Pages render()
pages: map state to props
```

So my question is: why is `mapStateToProps` being called multiple times on route changes?

Also, why does a simple `map` function in `mapStateToProps` cause it to be called a third time in the Posts container?

I am using the basic `logger` and `crashReporter` middlewares from the Redux docs and it is not reporting any state changes or crashes. If the state isn't changing why are the components rendering multiple times?

Comment: Any updates on this, by any chance?

Comment: Honestly, no. I started removing different things to see what could be triggering it. I just looked at it again and it seems like Redux's `@@INIT` action fires it an additional time, but it is hard to log that action. When rendering on the server it only logs a single `mapStateToProps` per container. Was hoping for an answer from @DanAbramov

Comment: I also looked at the Redux real-world example to see how many times mapStateToProps is being called there and it racks up a lot of calls. I'm thinking it's not quite that important as long as you use a tool like [Reselect](https://github.com/rackt/reselect) to memoize your selectors.

Comment: Last note: when changing routes (using react-router) I also only get a single `mapStateToProps` per container. So essentially, it is being called multiple times on page load only now.

Comment: Any update on this? I also have the same issue! Any input would be helpful!

Comment: Is your debugger running ? If you are using a redux debugger to monitor the state i think i have noticed a similar issue. Try building it (production mode/minify) and verify if it still happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Reselect](https://github.com/reactjs/reselect) allows you to create memoized selector functions for derived state processing.

[Redux's documentation](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/ComputingDerivedData.html) explains with an example how to use it. The repo's readme have a quick example too.

Comment: I solved this long ago, but going to accept this answer since Reselect is an awesome lib.

Comment: @Mike How did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 10):

By experience with `react-redux`, you should not process store attributes inside `mapStateToProps` because [`connect` uses shallow checking of bound store attributes to check for diff](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/src/connect/connect.js#L55).

To check if your component needs to be updated, `react-redux` calls `mapStateToProps` and checks the first level attributes of the result. If one of them changed (`===` equality check), the component will update with the new props. In your situation `posts` change (`map` transform) every time `mapStateToProps` gets called, so your component is updated on every store change!

Your solution would be to return only direct references of your store's attributes:

```
function mapStateToProps (state) {
  return {
    posts: state.entities.posts,
    users: state.entities.users
  };
}
```

Then in your component, you could define a function that processes your data on demand:

```
getPostsWithAuthor() {
  const { posts, users } = this.props;

  return map(posts, post => {
    return {
      ...post,
      author: findWhere(users, {_id: post.author})
    };
  });
}
```

Comment: it looks like your github link is dead....are you referring to this line?  https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/db91ed900107e58c15000e2a45c29e85c63ca2eb/src/connect/connect.js#L36

Comment: Indeed, the code of `connect.js` has moved and changed a lot, thank you @sfletche for notifying! Note that `connect` seems to accept custom update conditions now, so OP could actually tweak them specifically (even though I recommend not to transform anything in `mapStateToProps` but at the last moment inside the component)